is it common for attorneys and clients to interact entirely remotely online?
I am currently searching for patent attorneys. But I am only limiting my search to my city. I am wondering if that is unnecessary?
Is it common now for the clients and attorneys to interact entirely remotely online now?

With today's tools, I don't see why you couldn't work remotely with a patent attorney. I'd prefer secure portals for document exchange instead of email attachments, but even that could be avoided using password protected documents. I guess the only question is how to handle signatures. In any case the attorney should be able to answer those questions.
